# jQuery $ não é uma função/não está definido

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, webpack

Bom dia galera.
Estou a algum tempo tentando resolver isso mas sem sucesso.

Parece que o jQuery não está sendo carregado ou atribuído em `$`, `jQuery`.

Abaixo segue alguns trechos do código para ilustrar melhor como tentei incluir o jQuery.

----- Package.json -----

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
```

----- O `.extract()` no webpack.mix.js -----

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');

mix.sass('resources/admin/sass/app.scss', 'admin/css/app.css')
    .sass('resources/admin/sass/vendors/vendors.scss', 'admin/vendors/css/vendors.bundle.css')
    .scripts(
        [
            ...
        ],
        'public/admin/js/scripts.bundle.js'
    )
    .extract(
        [
           'jquery', 'popper.js', 'bootstrap', 'js-cookie', 'moment', 'tooltip.js',
           'perfect-scrollbar', 'sticky-js', 'wnumb'
        ],
       'admin/vendors/js/global_vendors.bundle.js'
    )
    .version();

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: 'popper.js',
            moment: 'moment'
        })
    ],
});
```

E no HTML acima da tag de fechamento `</body>`:

```html
<script src="{{ mix('/admin/js/pages/manifest.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/admin/vendors/js/global_vendors.bundle.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/admin/js/scripts.bundle.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Após todas as tentativas ainda da erro no `scripts.bundle.js` que é o último a ser carregado:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at scripts.bundle.js?id=d7fb6ba275af3d7aacaf:334
```

A linha que da erro é um `$(document).ready(function() {...})`.

**Obs. 1:** Se eu colocar o link do CDN do jQuery antes de todos os scripts tudo funciona.

**Obs. 2:** Utilizando o `require` no './bootstrap.js' no `app.js` e adicionando o `app.js` no HTML funciona.

**Obs. 3:** Os comandos em jQuery no console do navegador também dão o mesmo erro.

Estou faz tempo tentando entender pq com o webpack não da certo.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Já tentou chamar o arquivo js dentro da tag script?

Comment: Sem utilizar o `mix()` ?

Comment: Eu, particularmente uso assim `<script src="{{ URL('admin/js/pages/manifest.js') }}"> </script>` só meus arquivos ficam na pasta public

Comment: Alterando para `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL('/admin/vendors/js/global_vendors.bundle.js') }}"></script>` não resolveu... =/

Comment: Mas você está importando o jquery-3 antes dessa linha ai?

Comment: O jQuery está incluso nesse arquivo, ele é o resultado do `.extract()` que faço no webpack.

Comment: Pelo visto, seu nivel está muito avançado (sem ironia), é porque eu nunca usei com o webpack, só mesmo no html